# Не могу привести valueType к BigInteger

Tags: c#, biginteger

BitInteger у меня из `System.Numerics`.
Этот код выдает *InvalidCastException: Заданное приведение является недопустимым* на второй строке.

```
BigInteger bigint1 = (BigInteger)3455;
BigInteger bigint2 = (BigInteger)(ValueType)3455;
```

И все бы ничего, но на [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx) так делают, и все в порядке. Что я делаю не так?

Вообще, я пытаюсь написать оператор приведения типа 'To'. Для классов все просто, а вот для структур я пытаюсь реализовать такой метод:

```
public static T To<T>(this ValueType o)
```

И все же, на msdn есть такой код:

```
public static NumericRelationship Compare(ValueType value1, ValueType value2)
{

  // Use BigInteger as common integral type
  if (IsInteger(value1) && IsInteger(value2)) {
     BigInteger bigint1 = (BigInteger) value1;
     BigInteger bigint2 = (BigInteger) value2;
     return (NumericRelationship) BigInteger.Compare(bigint1, bigint2);
  }
}

public static bool IsInteger(ValueType value)
{         
  return (value is SByte || value is Int16 || value is Int32 
          || value is Int64 || value is Byte || value is UInt16  
          || value is UInt32 || value is UInt64 
          || value is BigInteger); 
}
```

Они же приводят к BigInteger, почему у меня этот код не работает?

Comment: @Rootware, да, так работает. Но мне надо приводить именно из ValueType.

Comment: Я ошибся. Не правильно понял самого вопроса. В той ссылке на MSDN используется иная модель. Вы можете объяснить, почему именно через ValueType вам это необходимо? Как понимаю он нужен всего лишь для определения является ли это числом, не строкой.

Comment: @Rootware, дополнил вопрос. Числом, а не другим объектом. В той ссылке есть еще метод IsNumeric. В принципе, мне нужен ValueType именно для этого, чтобы определить, число это или нет.

Comment: Ну так возьмите только метод для определения чем является переменная и преобразуйте если это число через парсер `BigInteger.Parse(value, NumberStyles.Integer)`. Для сравнения чего-либо нужно привести к общему типу. В примере это именно так и сделано. Даже комментарий оставлен `// Use BigInteger as common integral type`.

Comment: @Rootware, да, пожалуй, так и сделаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исключение вылетало, потому что в моем коде при приведении к valuetype туда заносится int, а я потом пытаюсь достать оттуда BigInteger. BigInteger не является супертипом для int, поэтому и получалась ошибка приведения. Нисходящее преобразование. [metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.11.php) | [msdn](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.11.php)